# What is the definition of the "cost" function in the SVM's objective function?

Tags: objective-functions, math, support-vector-machine, hinge-loss

In a course that I am attending, the cost function of a support vector machine is given by

$$J(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} y^{(i)} \operatorname{cost}_{1}\left(\theta^{T} x^{(i)}\right)+\left(1-y^{(i)}\right) \operatorname{cost}_{0}\left(\theta^{T} x^{(i)}\right)+\frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \Theta_{j}^{2}$$

where $\operatorname{cost}_{1}$ and $\operatorname{cost}_{0}$ look like this (in Magenta):

[image]

[image]

What are the values of the functions $\operatorname{cost}_{1}$ and $\operatorname{cost}_{0}$?

For example, if using logistic regression the values of $\operatorname{cost}_{1}$ and $\operatorname{cost}_{0}$ would be $-\log* \operatorname{sigmoid}(-z)$ and $-\log*(1-\operatorname{sigmoid}(-z))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the *[hinge loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss)*, a type of loss most notably used for SVM classification. The hinge loss is typically defined as:

$$
\ell(y)=\max (0,1-t \cdot y),
$$

which, in your use case, is something like this:

$$
\operatorname{cost}\left(h_{\theta}(x), y\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\max \left(0,1-\theta^{T} x\right) & \text { if } y=1 \\
\max \left(0,1+\theta^{T} x\right) & \text { if } y=0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Check [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimization-loss-function-under-the-hood-part-iii-5dff33fa015d) on it.